Using a shared JWT private key on two API servers
Shared key
I have two API servers A and B.
Server A has an authentication system, which grants a user an access token (JWT) to perform actions, and access restricted resources on server A.
I want server B to require the user to be an authenticated user from server A, in order to perform actions on server B.
Security wise, is it okay to have a shared JWT private key / secret on both server A and B to authenticate the user? If not, what would be the alternative?
Sensitive information
I am aware that JWT's can be easily decoded, and therefore it shouldn't contain sensitive information. Currently I am storing the user's email and MongoDB _id in the JWT, is this considered sensitive information?

If Server A creates the JWT and Server B validates it then Server B only needs a public key, not a private one. Also consider if you really need this or if you can just get away with a simple data base or session store.

I'm not really sure I know what a public key is in the context of JWT's. Could you perhaps give an example of how server B would validate the public key?

Being able to validate a JWT without needing a private key is a pretty fundamental JWT feature if you use assymetric encryption (which you should use).
